# Loading different types of files into a database

Tags: database, etl, data-warehouse, data-processing

At my work, we receive thousands of emails per day with attached files (xlsx, csv, xml, html, pdf, etc). Those emails get processed by a program and the files get downloaded and filtered into different folders depending on the sender.

The data in those files is then loaded into our MS SQL Server db by a proprietary software for which we are charged a hefty sum of money each year.

Now, I'm sure this is a super common process for enterprises, so there are probably some open source tools that we could use to replace this software.

How do most people do this? With individual scripts? What would be the correct way to do it?

Thank you very much!

EDIT: all the email attachments get converted to xlsx before being moved to their respective folders.

Answer (score -1):

The 'correct' way would be to not use Excel as the interchange format - its fuzzy notion of data types (e.g. numbers vs. text) creates many issues.

Still, Excel feeds are a fact of life, so it's crucial to have a comprehensive and reliable way of dealing with multiple feeds that sometimes fail. I like [this approach](https://docs.envobi.com/articles/process-incoming-files-example.html); the example uses my company's commercial [cross-platform .NET ETL library](https://envobi.com/), but I've also used the same approach with several other ETL tools previously.

Cheers,
Kristian

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I'm currently looking into using MS Data Factory, but it looks like it's only good for loading perfectly tabular files into a database. I think I will need to have a python script that reformats the spreadsheets into tables containing only the relevant information..